# Restart game by spacebar instead of pointerdown

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'd like to restart my game with the spacebar instead of of using my mouse. I was trying some things out, but it didn't work like:

```
this.restart.input.keyboard.on('keyup_SPACE', () => {
  this.dino.setVelocityY(0);
  this.dino.body.height = 92;
  this.dino.body.offset.y = 0;
  this.physics.resume();
  this.obsticles.clear(true, true);
  this.isGameRunning = true;
  this.gameOverScreen.setAlpha(0);
  this.anims.resumeAll();
})
```

This is what I have:

```
this.restart.on('pointerdown', () => {
  this.dino.setVelocityY(0);
  this.dino.body.height = 92;
  this.dino.body.offset.y = 0;
  this.physics.resume();
  this.obsticles.clear(true, true);
  this.isGameRunning = true;
  this.gameOverScreen.setAlpha(0);
  this.anims.resumeAll();
})

this.restart = this.add.image(0, 80, 'restart').setInteractive();
this.gameOverScreen.add([
  this.gameOverText,  this.restart
])
```

Comment: Do you have any variables that detects whether the game is over? Like "this.isGameRunning" ?  You can add a condition inside the "space key down listener", if the game still running, do jump action, otherwise re-start the game.

Comment: Yes I have. Here's the file where I'm using it, but i can't seem to figure it out..
https://codepen.io/Borsj/pen/YzZNQgq?editors=0010

Comment: In your  `" this.input.keyboard.on('keydown_SPACE', () => "` method, add the `"!this.isGameRunning"` check as the first condition and if it is not running anymore, restart the game and set the `"this.isGameRunning = true"` just like the the same as your `"this.restart.on('pointerdown', () =>"` method.

Comment: OMG, it was actually that simple. Guess I've been staring at my screen for too long. Thanks Steven!

Comment: No problem Bro, glad my answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `keyup` event like this (checking the `keyCode` corresponding to the spacebar):

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode === 32) console.log("Spacebar pressed");
});
```

You could restart the game when the spacebar is pressed, could look something like this.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) { 
      this.restart();
    }
});
```